# Why is a lazy var accessing a class property before this one had a value?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController that has a lazy UIView property:

```
class DetailView: UIViewController {
    var presenter: DetailPresenterProtocol?
    var heroData: MarvelData?
    var marvelDataCollection: [MarvelData]? {
        didSet {
            print("Initialized")
        }
    }

    lazy var bodyView: BodyDetailView = {
        print("Inside lazy var initialization")
        guard let data = marvelDataCollection else { return BodyDetailView(data: [], elems: "")}
        print(data)
        let body = BodyDetailView(data: data, elems: heroData?.description ?? "No description")

        return body
    }()
   ///More stuff over here
}
// MARK: - Lifecycle
extension DetailView {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        presenter?.viewDidLoad()
        title = heroData?.name ?? "No name"
        setupViews()//Here I set the lazy UIView
        print("Finished view did load")
    }
}
```

The problem is when unwrape data inside the lazy var, it is nil because "marvelDataCollection" has no value already.

This is the flow:

1. Inside lazy var initialization
2. Finished view did load
3. Initialized

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution that is based on calling the setupViews() inside the presenter callback(just after class properties instantiation) instead of viewDidLoad:

```
//MARK: - Presenter -> View
extension DetailView: DetailViewProtocol {
    func saveData(data: [MarvelData]) {
        marvelDataCollection = data
        setupViews()
    }
    
    func setupView(with data: MarvelData) {
        heroData = data
    }
}
```